# What should be the standard format for file-extension tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

We should definitely standardize how we want to handle file-extension tags, because there's already been some confusion.

Should we have:

- `.svg` or `svg`?
- `.stl` or `stl`?
- `.blend-files` or `blend-files`?
- etc...

This is closely related to the `blend-files`/`.blend-files` synonym request, but I think we should discuss this as a more general issue.

Comment: I'd opt for without the dot, but I'm interested to see what other people think

Comment: Tags generally avoid characters that are not either alphanumeric or a hyphen, from what I've seen on other sites.

Comment: @ObsessiveSSOℲ: So far as I know, hyphens are used to separate words *when needed*. So it's not so much avoiding their use as simply not overusing them.

Answer (score 11):

We should avoid the dots, as those refer to file extensions, not formats. Formats should be specified in the form of "svg", "blend", "obj-format", etc.

Comment: +1. No dots please.

Comment: Agreed. Some formats have multiple extensions anyway.